# Grid search on epochs in neural network: each parameter being run 3 times

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, grid-search

My sequential dense DNN seems to run through each parameter in my parameter grid three times while doing Grid Search. I expect it to run once per specified epcohs in the grid: 10, 50 and 100. Why does this happen?

model architecture:

```
def build_model():
    print('building DNN architecture')
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dropout(0.02, input_shape = (150,)))
    model.add(Dense(8, init = 'normal', activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.02))
    model.add(Dense(16, init = 'normal', activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, init = 'normal'))
    model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'adam')
    print('model succesfully compiled')
    return model
```

Grid search on epochs:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
epochs = [10,50,100]
param_grid = dict(epochs = epochs)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn = build_model), param_grid = param_grid)
grid_result = grid.fit(x_train, y_train)
grid_result.best_params_
```

Comment: can you add some data so that I could reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because GridSearchCV does both grid search and cross-validation. For each parameter combination, three (by default) splits are used for cross-validation, and this is why you see the model being trained three times for each parameter set.

You can change the number of folds (splits) with the "cv" parameter. Check it out in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html).